# Can anyone help me on implementation of Android Blur on version 4.0 and above without learning Renderscript

Tags: android, c++, android-layout, renderscript

Renderscript is too much C/C++ , i'm more comfortable with Java, can someone help me with a code that can be integrated over a layout to make the background image of the layout somewhat blurred.

Answer (score 1):

hey check out this link on blurring images..

http://blog.stylingandroid.com/archives/2304

Quote:

> ```
> private void blur(Bitmap bkg, View view, float radius) {
>
> Bitmap overlay = Bitmap.createBitmap(
>     view.getMeasuredWidth(), 
>     view.getMeasuredHeight(), 
>     Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
>
> Canvas canvas = new Canvas(overlay);
>
> canvas.drawBitmap(bkg, -view.getLeft(), 
>     -view.getTop(), null);
>
> RenderScript rs = RenderScript.create(this);
>
> Allocation overlayAlloc = Allocation.createFromBitmap(
>     rs, overlay);
>
> ScriptIntrinsicBlur blur = ScriptIntrinsicBlur.create(
>     rs, overlayAlloc.getElement());
>
> blur.setInput(overlayAlloc);
>
> blur.setRadius(radius);
>
> blur.forEach(overlayAlloc);
>
> overlayAlloc.copyTo(overlay);
>
> view.setBackground(new BitmapDrawable(
>     getResources(), overlay));
>
> rs.destroy(); }
> ```